# JoinColumn to an foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to achieve this with hibernate:
[image: table relationship]

My codes is as follows:

Device model

```
@Entity
public class Device {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(nullable = false)
private long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_user", nullable = true, referencedColumnName = "ID")
private User user;
...
}
```

Statistics model

```
@Entity
public class Statistic {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(nullable = false)
private long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "fk_device", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "fk_device_user", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "fk_user") })
private Device device;
...
}
```

However, there's an error saying there's no logical column fk_user in device.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: fk_user in device
```

I suppose it is because fk_user is a foreign key. But how can I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Based on you schema i would map the Device entity as follows:

public class Devince{

```
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = true)
  private User user;
  ...
  }
```

}

You dont need the `referencedColumnName` as you are referring to the `User` entity primary key. If you would refer to non-primary key column, then that would be necessary.

Regarding the Statistic entity:

```
public class Statistic {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "device_id", nullable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "device_user_id", nullable = false, 
  referencedColumnName = "user_id") })
  ...
  }
}
```

Again, you only need the `referencesColumnName` in the second `@JoinColumn`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I removed all the first `referencesColumnName` in `@JoinColumn`, but I still get the error message `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: user_id in device`.